# HTML CANVAS will support windows 7 and chrome beta version?

Tags: html, google-chrome, windows-7, beta

Will HTML5 canvas element be supported in Windows7 and Chrome beta latest version?

Comment: Check out this website: https://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

Comment: If it is not supported, Is there any website for os and browser compatibilty info?

Comment: How to check for specifically chrome beta versions? @CoyBit

Comment: Did you check out this page? https://caniuse.com/#comparison

Comment: Thanks @CoyBit, How we will know for specific OS version?

Comment: I should be OS-independent. If Chrome asserts it supports feature-X in version Y and above, it doesn't matter on which OS you are.